# Ruby check if constant is a class

Tags: ruby

I want to make a ruby `gem` which standardizes a serious of APIs.

The logic associated with connecting to each API needs to be abstracted into `.rb` files. To load each of the API's logic, I'm looping through the files of a folder:

```
# Require individual API logic
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/standard/apis/*.rb"].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

Each API is a constant of the `StandardAPI`, so I can to iterate some code over each API:

```
StandardAPI.constants.each do |constant|
  # Standardize this stuff
end
```

However, I have a `VERSION` constant too. It loops over my API logic classes just fine, but when I gets to `VERSION`, I run into:

`:VERSION is not a class/module (TypeError)`

How can I loop over each of the APIs ignoring constants that aren't my required classes?

Answer (score 5):

Since [`Module#constants`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-constants) returns an array of symbols, you have to first look up the constant with [`Module#const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get):

```
Math.const_get(:PI)              #=> 3.141592653589793
StandardAPI.const_get(:VERSION)  #=> the value for StandardAPI::VERSION
```

Then you can check if it is a class:

```
Math.const_get(:PI).class                    #=> Float
Math.const_get(:PI).is_a? Class              #=> false
StandardAPI.const_get(:VERSION).is_a? Class  #=> false
```

To filter all classes:

```
StandardAPI.constants.select { |sym| StandardAPI.const_get(sym).is_a? Class }
```

Another approach is to collect the sub classes, maybe with [`Class#inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited):

```
# standard_api/base.rb
module StandardAPI
  class Base
    @apis = []

    def self.inherited(subclass)
      @apis << subclass
    end

    def self.apis
      @apis
    end
  end
end

# standard_api/foo.rb
module StandardAPI
  class Foo < Base
  end
end

# standard_api/bar.rb
module StandardAPI
  class Bar < Base
  end
end

StandardAPI::Base.apis
#=> [StandardAPI::Foo, StandardAPI::Bar]
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you should be able to use [is_a?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F)

```
class Test
end

Test.is_a?(Class)
=> true

VERSION = 42

VERSION.is_a?(Class)
=> false
```

Comment: The issue with this is that StandardAPI.constants doesn't return an array of the constants themselves, but an array of symbols that match the constant names.

Comment: `const_get` might help you. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can catch that exception and proceed

```
StandardAPI.constants.each do |constant|
  begin
    # Standardize this stuff
    rescue TypeError
      next
  end
end
```

or as @jonas mentioned

```
StandardAPI.constants.each do |constant|
  if constant.is_a?(Class)
    # Standardize this stuff
  end
end
```